# Scala Swing: Changing BorderPanel central component new Component not visible

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I'm changing the centre area on a Scala Swing Border Panel. The old component disappears, but the new component does not appear, until I resize the window manually with the mouse. I've tried using different components and repainting, but nothing makes the new component appear except manually resizing the window with the mouse.

```
def splitDisp(mapCanv: VistaIn): Unit =
{
  val canv2 = newMapCanv         
  panel.layout(canv2) = BorderPanel.Position.Center
  canv2.repaint         
  thisScn.repaint //ref to the Frame instance
  panel.repaint 
  thisScn.repaint
  canv2.repaint
}
```

I'm using 2.10.0M5 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `revalidate()` and then `repaint()`.

Comment: Thanks. Revalidate on the BorderPanel seems sufficient, no need for repaint. I missed the revalidate because I looked in Frame which only has repaint.